# How to get PST time moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am struggling to get the PST time from moment. The requirement is to get the current PST time.

My code is

```
const momentTz = require('moment-timezone');
const pst = momentTz().tz('America/Los_Angeles').format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a z");            
console.log(pst)
```

It gives the time `2018-04-10 08:56 pm PDT`

which is PDT time and at this point the PST time is one hour lesser than this result which I verified with this [link](https://time.is/PST).

I think is this because day light saving thing? Could anyone help me on this please?

**UPDATE**

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145957/momentjs-timezone-getting-date-at-time-in-specific-timezone) is related to converting a specific time to a different timezone.

In my case I don't need any conversion. I am just passing current time like this

`momentTz().tz('America/Los_Angeles').format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a z");`

Now this gives me the time as I mentioned in PDT format.

As per docs

```
var jun = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
dec.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');  // 4am PST
```

the above code gives PST time and mine gives PDT time. I couldn't figure out the problem here.

**UPDATE 2**

As @sreekanth explained in the comment,

PST is coming in the date range which he mentioned and PDT otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Momentjs timezone - getting date at time in specific timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145957/momentjs-timezone-getting-date-at-time-in-specific-timezone)

Comment: @Sreekanth I had a look into that question and I couldn't get the answer . Do you mind explaining how is this duplicate please?

Comment: There is nothing like PST, during the Day light Saving time, which typically starts second Sunday in March to the first Sunday in November. PDT is the valid time given the timezone you are looking at and I dont think there exist PST during the timeframe

Comment: Thanks! I got the point now.